# parse all segments in a proxy fcgi error log file

Tags: php, regex

I try to parse this string:

```
[Wed May 06 15:09:08.160122 2015] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 30987:tid 140285789038336] [client 192.168.56.1:39157] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Undefined class constant 'self::TF_TEASER_LONG' in /var/www/foo/admin/server/php/UploadHandler.php on line 588\nPHP message: PHP Stack trace:\nPHP message: PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/foo/admin/server/php/index.php:0\nPHP message: PHP   2. UploadHandler->__construct() /var/www/foo/admin/server/php/index.php:14\nPHP message: PHP   3. UploadHandler->initialize() /var/www/foo/admin/server/php/UploadHandler.php:172\nPHP message: PHP   4. UploadHandler->post() /var/www/foo/admin/server/php/UploadHandler.php:187\nPHP message: PHP   5. UploadHandler->handle_file_upload() /var/www/foo/admin/server/php/UploadHandler.php:767\n', referer: http://foo.com/admin/module.php?id=29
```

What I expect as matches at the end would be:

```
1  -> Wed
2  -> May
3  -> 06
4  -> 15
5  -> 09
6  -> 08
7  -> 2015
8  -> proxy_fcgi:error
9  -> 192.168.56.1:39157
10 -> PHP Fatal error
11 -> Undefined class constant 'self::TF_TEASER_LONG'
12 -> /var/www/foo/admin/server/php/UploadHandler.php
13 -> 588
14 -> PHP message: PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/foo/admin/server/php/index.php:0\nPHP message: PHP   2. UploadHandler->__construct() /var/www/foo/admin/server/php/index.php:14\nPHP message: PHP   3. UploadHandler->initialize() /var/www/foo/admin/server/php/UploadHandler.php:172\nPHP message: PHP   4. UploadHandler->post() /var/www/foo/admin/server/php/UploadHandler.php:187\nPHP message: PHP   5. UploadHandler->handle_file_upload() /var/www/foo/admin/server/php/UploadHandler.php:767\n
15 -> http://foo.com/admin/module.php?id=29
```

I'm currently at this regex and already fail understanding basic principles:

```
/(\[(.*?)\])?((?<=\')(.*)(?=\'))?(, referer: (.*))*/g
```

1. Why do I have to put "?" behind the group `(\[(.*?)\])`?
2. Why does it only match those 4 bracket groups if I don't put the "?" in?
3. Why can't I put "{4}" behind the group in 1. to match it 4 times?

Here is a testcase:

https://regex101.com/r/cZ6rE3/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This string, You gave is very specyfic, so maybe my regex won't match to every of its "brothers", but it can look like this:

```
/\[(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.\d+\s(\d{4})\]\s*\[([^\]]+)\]\s\[[^\]]+\]\s\[client\s(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d+)\][^\']+\'[^:]+:\s([^:]+):\s+(.*?)\sin\s(.*?)\son\sline\s(\d+)\\n(.*?)referer:\s(.*)/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/dI9oO5/1

To answer Your questions:

1. `*` and `+` operators are "greedy", it means that by default they will match to as many characters they can. To change this behavior, You can add ?, So: `.*?` means: match to every character but stop as soon as You can (Don't be greedy.)
2. The greed of `*` (without ?) makes it to consume more caracters than You want and not much is left for rest of the pattern.
3. In described expected result You want to get every part of date in different varaible, so this is at least one reason why `(\[(.*?)\]){4}` won't work